# Im getting an error when creating my database (#1064)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I was trying to create a database using phpmyadmin but I keep on getting error

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,First Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,Last Name VARCHAR(30) NOT' at line 3`

Im using Tomcat version 8.0. Below is the query I am Executing

```
CREATE TABLE `cs485_lab5`.`Orders` (
    `Item Number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    `Price` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL, 
    `First Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    `Last Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    `Shipping Address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `Credit Card` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    `CCN` INT(16) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`Credit Card`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Show the *whole* error message

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,`First Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,`Last Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT' at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify a length for `DOUBLE`.  Also, if you are designing the table, don't put spaces in the column names.  Use names that don't need escaping.  Having to use escape characters just clutters up queries unnecessarily.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    `ItemNumber` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    `Price` DOUBLE NOT NULL, 
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    `LastName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    `ShippingAddress` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    `CreditCard` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    `CCN` INT(16) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`CreditCard`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95bea) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: great, this worked thank you for the SQL Fiddle and comments.